# An unpublished paper of Thurston about diffeomorphism groups

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

William Thurston has done many contributions in the field of diffeomorphism groups. But it seems that one of his papers entitled

"On the Structure of the Group of Volume Preserving Diffeomorphisms"

was never published. I want to know if any digital copy of this paper is available somewhere?

I asked this question on math.stackexchange, but it seems it is better to ask it again here. This is the link of essentially the same question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418717/an-unpublished-paper-of-thurston-about-diffeomorphism-groups